# Unixodbc yields "file not found" error when trying to query Snowflake via ODBC

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

So, we're trying to switch our Rails application from Redshift to Snowflake - using the provided ODBC driver from Snowflake and the unixODBC driver manager.

When testing on my personal Mac, it works flawlessly.

When testing on our staging environment on linux, we're getting a strange error:

> **[01000][unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib '/opt/libSnowflake.so' : file not found [ISQL]ERROR: Could not
>   SQLConnect**

even though this file definitely exists and there are permissions for it.

I found multiple references to this error (including a recent one, in Reddit) but never with an actual solution.

Everything seems to be 64 bit (unixODBC, the snowflake driver, the alpine linux distro it's being run on, etc.)

**UPDATE: When testing on a docker of ruby-2.6.3 and not ruby:2.6.3-alpine3.10 , it worked fine, so it seems to be an issue perhaps tied to alpine somehow?**

This is what I got when I tried to LDD the driver on Alpine:

> bash-5.0# ldd /tmp/snowflake_odbc/lib/libSnowflake.so
>       /lib/ld-musl-x86_64.so.1 (0x7f1f53af7000)
>       librt.so.1 => /lib/ld-musl-x86_64.so.1 (0x7f1f53af7000)
>       libdl.so.2 => /lib/ld-musl-x86_64.so.1 (0x7f1f53af7000)
>       libpthread.so.0 => /lib/ld-musl-x86_64.so.1 (0x7f1f53af7000)
>       libm.so.6 => /lib/ld-musl-x86_64.so.1 (0x7f1f53af7000)
>       libc.so.6 => /lib/ld-musl-x86_64.so.1 (0x7f1f53af7000)
>   Error loading shared library ld-linux-x86-64.so.2: No such file or directory (needed by /tmp/snowflake_odbc/lib/libSnowflake.so)
>   Error relocating /tmp/snowflake_odbc/lib/libSnowflake.so: backtrace_symbols: symbol not found
>   Error relocating /tmp/snowflake_odbc/lib/libSnowflake.so: __rawmemchr: symbol not found
>   Error relocating /tmp/snowflake_odbc/lib/libSnowflake.so: __register_atfork: symbol not found
>   Error relocating /tmp/snowflake_odbc/lib/libSnowflake.so: __strdup: symbol not found
>   Error relocating /tmp/snowflake_odbc/lib/libSnowflake.so: backtrace_symbols_fd: symbol not found
>   Error relocating /tmp/snowflake_odbc/lib/libSnowflake.so: __strtod_internal: symbol not found
>   Error relocating /tmp/snowflake_odbc/lib/libSnowflake.so: setcontext: symbol not found
>   Error relocating /tmp/snowflake_odbc/lib/libSnowflake.so: __strftime_l: symbol not found
>   Error relocating /tmp/snowflake_odbc/lib/libSnowflake.so: __strtok_r: symbol not found
>   Error relocating /tmp/snowflake_odbc/lib/libSnowflake.so: makecontext: symbol not found
>   Error relocating /tmp/snowflake_odbc/lib/libSnowflake.so: backtrace: symbol not found
>   Error relocating /tmp/snowflake_odbc/lib/libSnowflake.so: getcontext: symbol not found

Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: Have you tried a support ticket with Snowflake?  If you are using their ODBC drivers, then you should be able to get some help from them.  They will help you troubleshoot the issues and determine whether its a Unix flavor issue, or a driver bug, or something else.  Good luck!

Comment: Yes, but i'm also trying here just because it's kind of urgent so i want to shoot in all directions :). I just tested a dockerfile that isn't based on Linux Alpine distro and it worked. Unforutnately our production docker IS based on alpine so i'm not sure what to do...

Answer (score 1):

Snowflake ODBC is not supported on Alpine (which sucks since Apline is great). One issue is glib, though even if you get past that it doesn't seem to matter.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/release-notes/requirements.html#label-client-operating-system-support